# Understanding Quantum Harmonic Oscillator derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I'm using [this pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_04S13_Lec08.pdf) as a reference.

Basically, I want to solve equation 0.3, which can be simplified to equation 0.5. The solution is in the form 
$$ \Psi(u)=h(u)e^{\frac{-u^2}{2}}$$

where $h(u)$ can be expanded as a power series

$$h(u)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j $$

I reached:

$$ a_{j+2}=\dfrac{2j+1-\epsilon}{(j+2)(j+1)}a_j$$

The website I linked above claimed that setting $2j+1-\epsilon=0$ well terminate the series. How?

Wouldn't this only terminate every other term after $a_{j+2}$ so that every term will remain except $a_{j+2}$, $a_{j+4}$, $a_{j+6}$ and so on. So we still have an infinite series?

If I read correctly, apparently you can set the first term of the other series as 0 as well so that only $a_{j}$, $a_{j-2}$, $a_{j-4}$ and so on remain (this is the paragraph below 0.26). Why can we do this and what does this have to do with symmetry? Why must the other series start with a zero?

Comment: <Note that imposing this condition only terminates either the odd series or the even series
because the recursion relation is spaced by two. We need to separately insist that the aj = 0
for the other series. This is fine because it has been shown that if the potential is symmetric,
then the energy eigenfunctions can be taken to be either even or odd.>the quote is from the reference in OP

Comment: yeah, that's what I don't get

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is that the wavefunction must be normalizable.  Equations 0.23--0.25 show that if $j \to \infty$, then the power series becomes a non-normalizable wavefunction.  This means that the series must be finite.  The reasoning from Equation 0.22 shows that after some $j$, every other $j$ must be zero.  Since this doesn't provide any information about the $j$'s of opposite parity, those must be zero from the start.

In other words, ordinarily you have complete freedom to specify $a_0$ and $a_1$ (or at least, they would be determined by the initial conditions of your system).  But because you have imposed the condition that the resulting series represent a normalizable wavefunction, you've forfeited that complete freedom in specifying $a_0$ and $a_1$.  By imposing that condition, you are requiring that one of $a_0$ or $a_1$ = 0.